# How to monitor changes in a website?

Tags: c#, web, httpwebrequest, monitoring, httpwebresponse

So I've been working on this for a month but I found nothing on the net so I though that it might be possible to check changes in websites source code every minute but it seems it's source code is changing every second, so is there any problem in my coding or is there any other way to monitor a website's changes?

here's my code:

```
private void Startbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");                            
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader source = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
richTextBox1.Text = source.ReadToEnd();
timer1.Start();
timer1.Interval = 60000;

     }

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader source2 = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        RichTextBox checker = new RichTextBox();
        checker.Text = source2.ReadToEnd();
        if (richTextBox1.Text == "")
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = checker.Text;

        }
        else
        {


            if (richTextBox1.Text != checker.Text)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("somthing changed");
                richTextBox1.Text = checker.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No changes yet!");

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would suggest that when have to compare the actual contents of a page to a stored version you:

1. Compare a MD5 hash you've stored against the hash of the new one (not the contents everytime)
2. Remember that there are changing elements in a page that you may not regard as the page content changing...

Some servers will return a `Last-Modified` header which you could use to do a compare i guess.

Answer (score 0):

You have set timer interval to 5000 milliseconds which makes it 5 seconds only. So your code will run every 5 seconds. If you want to run your timer every minute, you should set it to 1000x60=60000 ms. I hope this helps.

Comment: I know about the intervals it's just an example but thanks I'll change it to avoid further questions about timer, the point is it always finds a change in the websites sourcecode!

Comment: I see. You meant the actual content change every second. Actually, if you see the response returned by above request, there is a lot of data and anything can change with each request. As far as I understand, in fact, every request and response is unique. So this way, with each of your request the response will be unique. The point is, you need to clarify what part you exactly want to compare and then just filter that part from the response and then compare it. But for that, you'll first have to explore "Respose" in detail and see what exactly changes with each request.